# Property of window object not found in component class in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Well i got **window** object like this and trying to get 'App' property from it

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
bootstrap(..., [provide(Window, {useValue: window})]);

constructor(private window: Window) {

}
```

But in my case

```
 'App' in this.window -> false
```

or

```
 this.window.hasOwnProperty('App') -> false
```

but in console it is **true** so there is object 'App' in window.

Comment: Might be a timing issue. Maybe `App` is only set later?

Comment: Well i tried to put this in different life-cycles hooks it's not working even in ngAfterViewChecked that is last hook @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: On window -> window.App

Comment: I mean where is the code that creates `window.App` and from where is it invoked?

Comment: Well i solved the problem, it was order of execution problem. I use list of scripts along with angular bundle and script that was making App was under angular bundle.

Comment: That's what I assumed - see my first comment :) glad to hear you fixed it.